# DIV height seems too large

Tags: html

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/Jpu5b/2/ - with a DIV that contains another DIV that contains an img. I haven't specified the width or height of the inner DIV so it takes on the width of the parent DIV and the height of the img it contains.

```
<div id='box'>
    <div id='innerBox'> 
            <img id='cateye' src='http://s20.postimg.org/ddh45wqnd/t_cateye.jpg'/>
     </div> 
</div>
```

My question is, why is the height of the inner div about 5px larger than the img it  contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code and it should fix it

```
#cateye {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `#innerBox { line-height: 0; }` probably works too.

Comment: img {display: block;} will solve the problem too. but i am wondering why it is happening. can anyone tell me the reason

Comment: the reason its happening is because the img is an inline element and therefore the line-height (which does not default to 0) effects it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep img as an inline element just add `line-height: 0;` to your reset.

So it would look like this:

```
 * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jpu5b/18/

Otherwise Michael St Clairs's answer will work well.